# Unexpected token '&lt;'

Tags: apex

```
List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact> {
    new Contact(FirstName = 'Joe',LastName='Smith',Department='Finance');
    new Contact(FirstName = 'Kathy',LastName='Smith',Department='Technology')
        Contact(FirstName = 'Caroline',LastName='Roth',Department='Finance')
        Contact(FirstName = 'Kim',LastName='Shain',Department='Education')};
    insert conList;
    List<Contact> listToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    for(Contact con : conList){
        if (Con.Department == 'Finance'){
            con.Title = 'Financial analyst';
            listToUpdate.add(con);
        }
    }
    Update listToUpdate;
```

Comment: Im getting the "unexpected token '&lt;'. " error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact> {
  new Contact(FirstName = 'Joe',LastName='Smith',Department='Finance');
  new Contact(FirstName = 'Kathy',LastName='Smith',Department='Technology')
      Contact(FirstName = 'Caroline',LastName='Roth',Department='Finance')
      Contact(FirstName = 'Kim',LastName='Shain',Department='Education')};
```

You omitted the `new` for the third and fourth Contact in the list instantiation and each list element is not separated by commas

It should be:

```
List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact> {
    new Contact(FirstName = 'Joe',LastName='Smith',Department='Finance'),
    new Contact(FirstName = 'Kathy',LastName='Smith',Department='Technology'),
    new Contact(FirstName = 'Caroline',LastName='Roth',Department='Finance'),
    new Contact(FirstName = 'Kim',LastName='Shain',Department='Education')
};
```